# Вывод элементов после сортировки Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs, сортировка

Есть вот такой смарт компонент

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import Filter from '../Filter';
import Sort from '../Sort';

import { getItems, selectItem, reverseItems, findItems } from '../../actions/items';

import './app.css';

const App = ({filterList, sortList,  onGetItems, onFindItems, reverseItems, onSelectItem}) => {

onGetItems();

return (
    <div>
        <Filter items={filterList} findText={onFindItems} reverseItems={reverseItems} selectItem={onSelectItem} />
        <Sort items={sortList} selectItem={onSelectItem} />
    </div>
)}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        filterList: state.items.filter(item => item.name.includes(state.filter.toLowerCase())),
        sortList: state.items,
    }
  }


 function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
     return bindActionCreators({
    onGetItems: getItems,
    onSelectItem: selectItem,
    onFindItems: findItems,
    reverseItems: reverseItems
}, dispatch)}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Есть вот такие экшны:

```
            let items = [];

            (function onGetItems() {
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', '/items.json', false);
                xhr.send();
                if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
                } else {
                    items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText.toLowerCase());

                    items.sort(function(a, b) {
                        if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
                        if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
                        return 0;
                    });
                }
            })();

            export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
                dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ITEMS', payload: items });
            }

            export const selectItem = (item)  => {
                console.log(item);
                return {
                    type: "ITEM_SELECTED",
                    payload: item
                }
            };

            export const reverseItems = (items)  => {
                console.log(items)
                return {
                    type: "REVERSE_ITEMS",
                    payload: items.reverse()
                }
            };

            export const findItems = (items)  => {
                return {
                    type: "FIND_ITEMS",
                    payload: items
                }
            };
```

И конечно же есть пара редьюсеров:

```
            const initialState = '';

            export default function filter(state = initialState, action) {
                switch (action.type) {
                    case 'FIND_ITEMS': return action.payload;
                    default: return state
                }
            }

            const initialState = [];

            export default function items(state = initialState, action) {
                switch (action.type) {
                    case 'ADD_ITEMS': return action.payload;
                    default: return state
                }
            }
```

А проблема в том, что action reverseItems делает реверс массива, всё ок. Но я не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы передать данные в state и чтобы он перерендарил компонент.

Я понимаю, что вопрос из разряда "это же основы". Но я только учусь и не могу увязать всё это в одну кучу) Бьюсь уже пару дней и не могу уловить как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
 export const reverseItems = (items)  => {
   console.log(items)
   return {
     type: "REVERSE_ITEMS",
     payload: items.reverse()
   }
 };

 export default function filter(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
     case 'FIND_ITEMS': return action.payload;
     default: return state
   }
 }
```

В `action` в `payload` вы передает `items.reverse()`, соответственно в `reducer` вы можете получить этот массив из `action.payload`.
Добавить в этот reducer обработку события `"REVERSE_ITEMS"`:

```
export default function filter(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FIND_ITEMS': return action.payload;
    case 'REVERSE_ITEMS': return action.payload;
    default: return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Это замечтально и это я понимаю, но как потом мне всё это передать в компонент Filter, при учёте того, что туда уже передаются изначально полученные данные и они в придачу фильтруются. И новые данные также должны быть отфильтрованы

Comment: Как у вас reducers комбинируется? Может вам как раз надо посмотреть в сторону combineReducers? Скорее всего в компоненте в mapStateToProps вам нужно получать элементы из state.filter

Comment: combineReducers также используется. в state.filter передаётся просто введенный текст в инпут и исходя из него филтруются все items

Comment: Тогда попробуйте добавить в reducer items обработку case 'REVERSE_ITEMS': return action.payload;

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны реверсировать ваш массив в редьюсере а не в экшене. Экшена диспатчится в стор, редьюсер меняет стейт (ваш массив), а изменение стерта уже влечет ререндер компонента.

```
function app(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REVERSE_ITEMS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        items: action.payload.reverse()
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Ваш компонент должен быть задекорирован при помощи connect

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Filter from '../components/Filter'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    items: state.items
  }
}

const Filter = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Filter)

export default Filter
```